# How to use local storage in style.backgroundColor in JS?

Tags: javascript, css, local-storage, thread-local-storage

I'm trying to set a dark mode and light mode option. I have two buttons and I'm using on click function to change the background color, but I want to use this in multiple pages so that when I click on the dark mode, even after a refresh or going in another page, it remains the same dark mode.

```
<li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-widget="navbar-search" href="#" role="button" onclick="dark()">
          <i class="far fa-moon"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
    
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-widget="navbar-search" href="#" role="button" onclick="light()">
          <i class="fas fa-sun"></i>
        </a>
    </li>

<script>
          function dark(){
            
            document.getElementsByClassName("content-wrapper")[0].style.backgroundColor="#454D55";
            localStorage.setItem("color", "#454D55");
        }
        
        function light(){
            document.getElementsByClassName("content-wrapper")[0].style.backgroundColor = "#F4F6F9";
        }
      </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function dark(){
    document.getElementsByClassName("content-wrapper")[0].style.backgroundColor = "#454D55";
    localStorage.setItem("uniquekey", "#454D55");
}
        
function light(){
    document.getElementsByClassName("content-wrapper")[0].style.backgroundColor = "#F4F6F9";
    localStorage.setItem("uniquekey", "#F4F6F9");
}
```

You omitted the function to set value in the `light` function.

Answer (score 0):

You got it right there. You only need to listen to load event and get the color from the localStorage.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body class="content-wrapper" onload="loadTheme()">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-widget="navbar-search" href="#" role="button" onclick="dark()">
         nmnmn <i class="far fa-moon"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
    
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-widget="navbar-search" href="#" role="button" onclick="light()">
         mnmnmnkjkj <i class="fas fa-sun"></i>
        </a>
    </li>

<script>
function loadTheme() {
  let color = localStorage.getItem("color")
  document.getElementsByClassName("content-wrapper")[0].style.backgroundColor=color;
}
          function dark(){
            let color = "#454D55"
            document.getElementsByClassName("content-wrapper")[0].style.backgroundColor=color;
            localStorage.setItem("color", color);
        }
        
        function light(){
            let color = "#F4F6F9";
            document.getElementsByClassName("content-wrapper")[0].style.backgroundColor =color ;
            localStorage.setItem("color", color);
        }
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  Can you please tell me how did you store the color in local storage?

Comment: You need to create a variable color and assign the color to it. Then you need to localStorage.setItem("color", color)

Answer (score 0):

So at first glance, it seems you have to save your initial background color in localStorage when the DOM has just loaded. You can have something like this work for your case by following these simple steps:

1. Check for when the DOM has loaded
2. Check for default mode color, if the color doesn't exist then you set it in localStorage and apply the color to the DOM element.
3. Finally, add the `DOMContentLoaded` event listener, and pass your function that sets/check the default mode to it as a callback.
4. Define your `light()` and `dark()` functions as well and you should be ready to see your changes take effect.
5. Look at a simple implementation below:

List item

```
function ready(){
   let color;
   const mode = localStorage.getItem("color")
   if(!mode){
   //set default mode color here
     color = "#000"
     localStorage.setItem("color", "#000")
     return document.getElementsByClassName("content-wrapper")[0].style.backgroundColor = color;
   }

   document.getElementsByClassName("content-wrapper")[0].style.backgroundColor=color;
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);

function dark(){
        
        document.getElementsByClassName("content-wrapper")[0].style.backgroundColor="#454D55";
        localStorage.setItem("color", "#454D55");
    }
    
    fu

nction light(){
        document.getElementsByClassName("content-wrapper")[0].style.backgroundColor = "#F4F6F9";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution brother. I need to know how can I store the initial background color in localStorage. It would be great if you can show me a demo in fiddle?

Comment: Sorry for being late, here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fode17u3/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, I have done this by using cookies. I think it's much easier to use cookies.

Working Fiddle: **https://jsfiddle.net/fode17u3/**

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-light color-btn" data-color="#F4F6F9" ><i class="fas fa-sun"></i> Light Mode</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-dark color-btn" data-color="#454D55" ><i class="far fa-moon"></i> Dark Mode</button>
```

**CSS**

```
[data-color="black"] { 
    background: #454D55; 
   
}
[data-color="white"] {
    background: #F4F6F9;        
}
```

**Javascript**

```
 window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var cookieValue = getCookie('backgroundColor'),
        btns = document.querySelectorAll('.color-btn');



    if (cookieValue) {
        setBackgroundColor(cookieValue);
    }

    Array.from(btns).forEach(function (btn) {
        btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
            var color = this.getAttribute('data-color');
            setBackgroundColor(color);
        });
    });
});

function setBackgroundColor(color) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("content-wrapper")[0].style.backgroundColor = color;
    setCookie('backgroundColor', color);
    console.log(color);
}

function getCookie(name) {
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(';'),
        cookie = cookies.find(function (str) {
            return str.indexOf(name + '=') === 0;
        });
    if (cookie) {
        return cookie.split('=')[1];
    }
    return null;
}

function setCookie(name, value) {
    document.cookie = name + '=' + value;
}

var expiry = new Date();
    expiry.setFullYear(expiry.getFullYear() + 1);
    document.cookie = name + '=' + value + '; expires=' + expiry.toUTCString() + ';';
```